# BSOD after installing VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I have recently installed VirtualBox, then after restarting my PC on startup it blue screens. I started it in safe mode with the intention of uninstalling VirtualBox but am met with the error when uninstalling "the mobile installer service is unavailable in safe mode." When starting in safe mode with networking i get a blue screen so I am assuming it is to do with network drivers.

Comment: Whats the STOP code? Are you sure its caused by virtualbox? Just try disabling VBox network and other drivers in safe mode..

Comment: That's what I'm doing, and I can't see why it would be caused by anything else as that is all I did in my last session on the computer

Comment: I am not talking about uninstalling VBox. Disable its virtual devices from device manager.

Comment: I have disabled all networking devices (I couldn't find any ones but networking) and it is still causing a bluescreen.

Comment: With my limited knowledge I think it is definitely a networking driver issue as when attempting to start in safe mode with networking it also causes a blue screen.

Comment: Try system restore..

Answer (score 2):

Disable virtualbox drivers in safe mode Use autoruns to find all the drivers I see 5 total not all network

Comment: I have disabled all the virtualbox drivers I could find (all of them were in network) and I got a total of 5. What is autoruns and how do I get it?

Comment: @Chris - Autoruns is an official Microsoft support tool available on Microsoft's website.

Comment: Currently the computer with the problems is unable to access the internet due to the problem specified and I have no portable media, any suggestions on how to transfir the file?

Comment: I found an old USB and loaded autoruns on it and opened it in safe mode. I disabled 5 drivers (VBoxDrv, VBoxNetAdp, VBoxNetFlt, VBoxUSBMon and VGPU(I assume this is a virtualbox driver, it was yellow and saying "File not found")) but the same thing still seems to be happening.

Comment: Should also be VBoxUSB without the Mon. Don't have the driver VGPU but if its not from Oracle its not virtualbox related. Also to access the Internet on a machine that has a failing OS I boot to a live Linux CD